# ORA-01036 with oci_bind_by_name

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to make a SELECT from PHP to Oracle database.

Here is the code i did:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM
        DEV_F.FO_INPUT i,
        DEV_F.FO_MAIN m
        WHERE m.FOM_ID = i.FIN_FATHER
        AND m.FOM_ID = :traceID";

    $stid = oci_parse($this->connexion(), $sql);


    oci_bind_by_name($stid, 'traceID', $this->escapeString($traceID));

    oci_execute($stid);
    oci_fetch_all($stid, $res);
```

The request is OK in SQLDevelopper, returns no error, . But php returns:

> oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

I tried to add single quotes, to add semicolons etc… Nothing works, i'm pretty stick here.

Any tips ? Did i miss something ?

Comment: think there must be a `:` before the variable name: `oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':traceID', $this->escapeString($traceID));`

Comment: Perhaps you can try without calling escapeString?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this, first use a colon but also you do not need to escape the value because the binding will handle that for you.

```
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':traceID', $traceID);
```